# Object destructuring in the function parameters in react

Tags: reactjs

I am new to the ES6 Features, I have following code,

I have following component.

```
    function ToDo() {
    
      const onChange = ({target: {value}}) => {
        console.log(target)
      }
     
    
    return (
    <input type="text" onChange={onChange} value={item.text} /> 
    )
}
```

Here I did not understand the part of object destructuring in the `onChange` function. Where it should have been like `event.target.value`

Thanks

Comment: It's saying "give me a property `target` of the argument object, and then give me the property `value` of the `target` object". I don't think it is particularly readable.

Comment: `onChange` expects event object as a parameter. Event object has `target` property which, in turn, has `value` property. So, essentially, you may think of destructuring function parameter as a way of expressing (through the _shape_ of the input object) exact nested property, which becomes a variable with corresponding name inside function body.

Answer (score 1):

### Object destructuring

Object destructuring is just syntactic sugar for extracting values from an object. See the following:

```js
const person = {name: "Peter", computer: {model: "macbook", ram: 16}}
const { name } = person; // this would give "Peter"
const { computer } = person; // this would give {model: "macbook", ram: 16}

// now the tricky part. Just re-uses the same destructuring-syntax twice :) 
const { computer: { model }} = person; 
console.log(model) // gives "macbook"

// the lines above are essentially the same as this: 
const { computer } = person; // first getting computer 
const { model } = computer; // then getting the model
console.log(model); //also gives "macbook"
```

### Your code

If you log `value` instead of `target`, you should see the value of `event.target.value`.

```
function ToDo() {
  const onChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    console.log(target, value);
  };

  return <input type="text" onChange={onChange} value={item.text} />;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here `const onChange = ({target: {value}})=> ...`  on change argument is `event` object that you have extracted target from event, since target itself is an object, you then extracted `value` from `target`.

```
event looks this shape: { ..., target: { ..., value: 'some value' } }
```